# Creating dict from all possible combinations of 2 separate lists

Tags: python, python-2.x

I found this useful bit of code among the series of tubes that is the internet:

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[1,2,3,4]
combos=[(`i`+`n`) for i in x for n in y]
combos
['11','12','13','14','21','22','23','24','31','32','33','34','41','42','43','44']
```

What I'm trying to do is something like the following:

```
combinations={(i: `n`+`d`) for i in range(16) for n in x for d in y}
combinations
{1: '11', 2: '12', 3: '13', 4: '14', 5: '21', 6: '22'...etc}
```

But obviously that's not working. Can this be done? If so, how?

Comment: What do you want the dictionary keys to be?

Comment: Just numbers in a specified range if possible.

Comment: Note that (1) backticks as shortcut for `repr` is removed in 3.x and arguably a bad idea even in 2.x and (2) the `itertools` module has a generalization of this and several related algorithms. Also, why are you using a dictionary if the keys are consecutive integers? That's what lists are for.

Comment: Well because I'm trying to generate objects from this dict with a name variable of 'x'+'y' and two more variables to store x and y separately:
`for i in adict:
    alist.append(object(i, int(adict[i][0]), int(adict[i][1])))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
combos = [str(i) + str(n) for i in x for n in y] # or `i`+`n`, () for a generator
combinations = dict((i+1,c) for i,c in enumerate(combos))
# Only in Python 2.6 and newer:
combinations = dict(enumerate(combos, 1))
# Only in Python 2.7 and newer:
combinations = {i+1:c for i,c in enumerate(combos)}
```

Comment: Note that this will start from the keys at 0, not at 1 (I believe there is a keyword argument to change that) and can save a large intermediate list by using generator expressions.

Comment: Wow I feel dumb. Thanks philhaq! Stackoverflow to the rescue again. :)

Comment: @delnan Fixed and updated with an even nicer version that uses the start argument of enumerate.

Answer (score 1):

Start with your first example:

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[1,2,3,4]
combos=[(`i`+`n`) for i in x for n in y]
```

then just add:

```
combinations = {i: c for i, c in enumerate(combos)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You ... probably ... don't want that.  At least, there's not a great reason to need it that I can see.  if what you're after is being able to track their positions you want the result to be a list, which it already is.  If you need to know the indexes you should do something like this:

```
for idx, combo in enumerate(combinations):
  print idx+1, combo
```

If you actually need them accessible by position (and by list index + 1) you can do something like this:

```
lookup = dict((idx+1, combo) for idx, combo in enumerate(combinations))
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, there is a [`product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function in `itertools` module that can be used here

```
from itertools import product
x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[1,2,3,4]

combs = {i+1: ''.join(map(str,p)) for i,p in enumerate(product(x,y))}
```

`''.join(map(str,p))` is the code to convert all the items of `p` (which is `tuple` of `int-s`) into `str` and then join them using `''.join(...)`. If you don't need this, just leave `p` instead of this code.

Also, note, that the syntax `{j for j in js}` works only from Python 2.7